# PAM and LDAP with variable base DN

Tags: ldap, pam

I have a network of computers which are using LDAP for user authentication (Free IPA v1.2).  I am using the same LDAP server, but a different DN subtree, for external users of a web portal.  I have just added a new third party web application which uses PAM to authenticate users, so I've added

```
auth      required       pam_ldap.so
account   required       pam_ldap.so
```

to the `/etc/pam.d/new_webapp` PAM configuration file.  The problem is that this uses `/etc/ldap.conf` which looks to authenticate users from the **system** base DN (i.e. users who can ssh in with a username/password), but instead I'd like it to use a different base DN: the one associated with the **web portal** users.  I had hoped `/etc/pam_ldap.conf` might help me with this, but no luck.  What would be beautiful would be if I could do something like:

```
auth      required       pam_ldap.so conf /etc/ldap_web.conf
```

or

```
auth      required       pam_ldap.so base "cn=accounts, cn=webportal, dc=example, dc=com"
```

I'm looking for suggestions on how I can solve this.  The only other thing I can think of is to compile an alternative `pam_ldap.so` that looks at an alternative configuration file.

Thanks in advance for any feedback on this problem.

Ian

Here is the exception I get when I try to login with a user that is *only* on the webportal (web i/f):

```
Apr 29 02:22:31 portal rserver[7341]: ERROR pam_authenticate failed: User not known to the 
underlying authentication module; LOGGED FROM: int server::pam_auth::
<unnamed>::PAMAuth::login(const std::string&, const std::string&)
/root/rstudio/src/cpp/server/ServerPAMAuth.cpp:201
```

And this is the error when I try to login with a user that *does* have a system account:

```
Apr 29 02:22:48 portal rserver[7342]: ERROR pam_authenticate failed: Module is unknown;
LOGGED FROM: int server::pam_auth::<unnamed>::PAMAuth::login(const std::string&
const std::string&) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/server/ServerPAMAuth.cpp:201
```

Comment: Please tell us which OS your speaking about. Afaik there are different solutions for different systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do exactly what you're asking for. Use:

```
auth        required       pam_ldap.so config=/etc/ldap_web.conf
```

See the [man pag](http://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_ldap)e for more details.